# How to convert hex number to decimal stored in a DWORD instead QWORD?

Tags: python, bash, hex, decimal, dword

I have the hex number:

```
FFFFFCE3
```

Then if I'm trying to convert it to decimal number. I did:

```
printf "%d" "0xFFFFFCE3"
```

And outputs:

```
4294966499
```

But this is the result if I store it in a QWORD.
I want to know how to store it in a DWORD, so the ouput would be the negative number that I'm expecting:

```
-797
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm afraid I had already searched this. Could you post any example, or maybe a link whit the info?

Comment: How do you store it in dword/qword in bash? I believe, you cannot control that in bash.

Comment: Ok, then how I could make that `FFFFFCE3` coueld be converted to `-797` instead `4294966499`. I thought in check the first character of the hex, and if it's `F`, fill the number to generate this: `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFCE3`. What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: Show your code (a .sh script) with both examples. I am not getting `-797` output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To interpret a hex string as a 32-bit signed integer, run:

```
$ python -c 'x=int("0xFFFFFCE3",16); print x if x<2**31 else x-2**32'
-797
```

Explanation:

- `x=int("0xFFFFFCE3",16)`

  This converts a base-16 string to an unsigned integer.
- `print x if x<2**31 else x-2**32'`

  This converts an *unsigned* 32-bit integer into a *signed* 32-bit integer and prints it.